# how to get address detail of contacts in android

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch  saved contacts in android.here is the code and writing it to csv file.

```
 if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
      writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        data.add(new String[] {"Name", "Number","Email","Note","PoBox","street","City","State","Postal Code","Country","AddressType","Instant Messanger","Org Name","Org Title"});
     while (cur.moveToNext()) {
         String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
          name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
             if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                 // get the phone number
             Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);
             while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                   String phonetemp = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                   if(pCur.getCount()>1)
                   {
                       phone=phone+phonetemp+"^";
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       phone=phone+phonetemp;
                   }
                  }
             pCur.close();


             // get email and type
            Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

             while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                 // This would allow you get several email addresses
                     // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                 if(emailCur.getCount()>0)
                 {
                     if(emailCur.getCount()>1)
                     {
                       String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                       String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                       Emails=Emails + email + " $ " + emailType+"^";
                     }else
                     {
                         String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                         String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                         Emails=  email + " $ " + emailType;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Emails=null;
                 }
            }
             emailCur.close();

             // Get note.......
             String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
             String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE};
             Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
             if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
               Note= note;
             }
            noteCur.close();

             //Get Post Box Address....
            // String addrPoBoxWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            // String[] addrPoBoxWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrPoBoxCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrPoBoxCur.moveToNext()) {
                String poBoxtemp = addrPoBoxCur.getString(addrPoBoxCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                if(poBoxtemp!=null)
                {
                    if(addrPoBoxCur.getCount()>1)
                    {
                        poBox=poBox+poBoxtemp+"^";  
                    }
                    else {
                        poBox=poBox+poBoxtemp;
                    }

                }

                 }
             addrPoBoxCur.close(); 

             //Get Street Address....
             //String addrStreetWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
             String[] addrStreetWhereParams = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET};
             Cursor addrStreetCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,addrStreetWhereParams,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrStreetCur.moveToNext()) {
                  String streettemp = addrStreetCur.getString(addrStreetCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                  if(streettemp!=null)
                  {
                      if(addrStreetCur.getCount()>1)
                      {
                          street=street+streettemp+"^";   
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          street=street+streettemp;
                      }
                  }
             }
             addrStreetCur.close();

             //Get City Address....
            // String addrCityWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            // String[] addrCityWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrCityCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrCityCur.moveToNext()) {
                  String citytemp = addrCityCur.getString(addrCityCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                  if(citytemp!=null)
                  city=city+citytemp+"^";
             }
             addrCityCur.close();

             //Get State Address....
           //  String addrStateWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
          //   String[] addrStateWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrStateCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrStateCur.moveToNext()) {
                               String statetemp = addrStateCur.getString(addrStateCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                  if(statetemp!=null)
                  {
                      if(addrStateCur.getCount()>1)
                      {
                          state=state+statetemp+"^";      
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          state=state+statetemp;
                      }
                  }

              }
             addrStateCur.close();

             //Get PostalCode Address....
            // String addrPostalCodeWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
             //String[] addrPostalCodeWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrPostalCodeCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrPostalCodeCur.moveToNext()) {
                   String postalCodetemp = addrPostalCodeCur.getString(addrPostalCodeCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.PHONETIC_NAME));
                   if(postalCodetemp!=null)
                   {
                       if(addrPostalCodeCur.getCount()>1)
                       {
                           postalCode=postalCode+postalCodetemp+"^";       
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           postalCode=postalCode+postalCodetemp;
                       }
                   }

             }
             addrPostalCodeCur.close();

             //Get Country Address....
           //  String addrCountryWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
          //   String[] addrCountryWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrCountryCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrCountryCur.moveToNext()) {
                String countrytemp = addrCountryCur.getString(addrCountryCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                   if(countrytemp!=null)
                   {
                       if(addrCountryCur.getCount()>1)
                       {
                           country=country+countrytemp+"^";    
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           country=country+countrytemp;
                       }
                   }

               }
             addrCountryCur.close();

             //Get AddressType ....
           //  String addrAddressTypeWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            // String[] addrAddressTypeWhereParams = new String[]{id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor addrAddressTypeCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id},null);
             while(addrAddressTypeCur.moveToNext()) {
                   String AddressTypetemp = addrAddressTypeCur.getString(addrAddressTypeCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
                   if(AddressTypetemp !=null)
                   {
                       if(addrAddressTypeCur.getCount()>1)
                       {
                           AddressType=AddressType+AddressTypetemp +"^";       
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           AddressType=AddressType+AddressTypetemp;
                       }
                   }

                                     // Do something with these...
             }
             addrAddressTypeCur.close();

             // Get Instant Messenger.........
            String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
              while (imCur.moveToNext()) {
                 if(imCur.getCount()>0)
                 {
                     String imName = imCur.getString(
                              imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                     String imType;
                     imType = imCur.getString(
                              imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                     IM=IM + imName + " $ " + imType+"^";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     String imName = imCur.getString(
                              imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                     String imType;
                     imType = imCur.getString(
                              imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                     IM=IM + imName + " $ " + imType;
                 }

             }
             imCur.close();

             // Get Organizations.........
             String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
             String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
             Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                         null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
             if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                  orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));

                  title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
             }
             orgCur.close();
         }   data.add(new String[] {name, phone,Emails,Note,poBox,street,city,state,postalCode,country,AddressType,IM,orgName,title});
     }
     writer.writeAll(data);
     writer.close();
```

Issue here is whle facing  street detail of contact it is fetching street detail + contact number

Comment: When you debug the code and looping throught addrStreetCur, what are the values of "streettemp"?

Comment: @Axarydax : As i have saved only one contact in device for testing but cursor shows 10 number of records and while looping first time it fetch correct record after that it fetches all phone numbers of that contact